# Visual Studio 2012 crash ans restart automatically when i use Tools box

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8

I've installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate in Windows 8.

Every time I choose Tools | Options, it crashes and restarts .

I checked online, but can't find anything concrete to solve the issue.

Comment: Anything in the Event Viewer? What OS?

Comment: Did you add any recent packages to your Visual Studio?

Comment: no sir i just installed it

Comment: Have you applied the updates?

Comment: i did nothing on my visual studio just installed

Comment: First thing I would do if apply the available update http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39305

Comment: Use VS 2015. It's the latest version with tons of bug fixes and new features.

Answer (score 0):

Run install again and choose

```
Repair
```

looks like it was installed incorrect.